# Read Excel file and see if any of the words match my dictionary in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

So what I want to do is for my program to read my Excel file in the form of CSV. In the CSV there is a column filled with sentences, I want to check if any of the words in the sentences match my keys in Python, and then print the values one column to the right of the original column if it matches. Can this be done? 
So far I have only came up with this:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = pd.read_excel('mydict.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
project = pd.read_csv('project1.csv',sep=",",usecols=(3,))

for line in project:
    if key in my_dict.items():
        #print value one column to the right of original column
```

Example row from csv:

Hey you 'avin a giggl' thr m8?

Example dict:

'avin = Having

giggl' = Giggle

thr = There

m8 = Mate

Comment: Done! Sorry if I wasn't being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your `line` into words
2. Loop the words
3. `if word in my_dict:
          print(key ,my_dict[key])`

Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.